# Ignore \r and \b in iTerm2

Tags: printf, iterm2

`\r` and `\b` help a lot in reducing amount of progress updates, but how do I disable those characters in iTerm2 to show all lines instead?

e.g.: if program print

```
printf("\ra");
printf("\rb");
```

I will receive

```
a
b
```

instead of just

```
b
```

Comment: Why are you outputting `\r` in the first place if you dont want it?

Comment: @RemyLebeau No, I didn't control the code. But I'm annoyed of people abusing it.